# SCardTransmit returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when dwMaxCCIDMessageLength is more than 4KB

Tags: parameters, smartcard, pcsc, winscard

I'm developing a usb-smartcard & I use windows PC/SC API to transmit data with that smartcard. This is part of my code:

```
if(SCardConnect(hSC, sCard, SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, &hCard, &dwActiveProtocol) == SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
{
    if(SCardTransmit(hCard, SCARD_PCI_T1, pSendBuf, ulSendBufLen, SCARD_PCI_T1, pRecBuf, pulRecBufLen) == SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

**I'm sure size & pointers to both in/out buffers are valid.**

Until `dwMaxCCIDMessageLength` field of device descriptor is lower than `0x00001000h`, there is no problem & program works fine, but when I increase it to a larger value (more than 4kb), `SCardTransmit` fails with ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER result code.

Currently, I know the `pSendBuf` content was received successfully by the smart card & processing the content has completed, but when card wants to return a response, that error occurs & I think this is some kind of inconsistency (e.g buffer size limitation) in PC/SC driver.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

That the driver is the bottleneck is highly unlikely, and given that you have an USB interface I would also not assume, that the protocol layer is suspect. This leaves the smart card chip as the prime suspect, and since many new chips have 8 KB RAM in total, I find it understandable, that they don't devote the better part of it to the I/O buffer. Having no idea of the affected command, I would advise to try chaining or chunk-wise reading of a file.